# ros gazebo worlds problem

Tags: ros, gazebo, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am a beginner to ROS and gazebo. I get the following problem when I try launching gazebo simulator. On entering "rosmake gazebo worlds" I get a message gazebo_worlds ROS_NOBUILD in package gazebo_worlds. I get the same message for each package. Plz help........

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44860/ros-gazebo-worlds-problem/) by [Vishnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3010/vishnu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-10-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's not a problem. It just means that the package is already built and that it was installed from Debian packages. Did you try to run gazebo?

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vishnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3010/vishnu/) on 2012-10-01**:
Yes sir, but when I tried launching gazebo I get a problem again. I used this code roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world_no_x.launch . But I get an error